# Protobuf ignoring bool and ints values due to default

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto3

I am converting a json file to string and then the string is converted to proto3 file.

Here is the json file:

```
{    "a": false,
     "b": 0
}
```

Here is how I convert my json file to string:

```
String json =Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath)).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Here is how I convert my string to proto3 file:

```
    JsonFormat.parser().ignoringUnknownFields().merge(json,messageBuilder);
   MyProto proto = messageBuilder.build();
```

I have boolean and int fields in my json , the values of some of them are required to be default values (false for boolean and 0 for int).

When I deserialise the above file to proto3 java file then both the above fields are ignored , and my json becomes empty even though I have explicitly set the values(as you can see it in the above json file).

I know that proto3 ignores the default values while deserializing/serializing , however is there any way not to ignore fields which are explicitly set even though they are the default values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Used proto2 instead of proto3 .  Proto2 has this behaviour - if a field is explicitly set , even though it is default value of the field , it is serialized and deserialized .

Answer (score 3):

No, the [Protobuf language guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#default) states explicitly that this is not possible:

> Note that for scalar message fields, once a message is parsed there's
>   no way of telling whether a field was explicitly set to the default
>   value (for example whether a boolean was set to false) or just not set
>   at all: you should bear this in mind when defining your message types.
>   For example, don't have a boolean that switches on some behaviour when
>   set to false if you don't want that behaviour to also happen by
>   default. Also note that if a scalar message field is set to its
>   default, the value will not be serialized on the wire.

If you really must know wether the default value was set explicitly or not you have encode that information in a separate field.

Comment: Or use an `Int32Value` or `StringValue` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 3.15, protobuf3 allows for explicit presence tracking via the [`optional`](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/field_presence/) keyword.

That is, given

```
message MyProto
{
    optional int32 field = 1;
}
```

protoc will generate a `has_field()`/`hasField()` (depending on language) function to check if the field has been explicitly set.

(Note: protobuf3 fields are optional by default, the `optional` keyword makes them "nullable").

Another option is to use the "[well known](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/)" wrapper messages:

```
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto"

message MyProto
{
    Int32Value field = 1;
}
```

However, their use is [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/design_patterns.md#optional_primitive_fields).